# How is Iran able to project its power?

Tags: iran

[Syria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_involvement_in_the_Syrian_Civil_War), [Yemen](https://warontherocks.com/2017/06/irans-growing-casualty-count-in-yemen/), Lebanon, Iraq, [Argentina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMIA_bombing), and so on ... Iran is everwhere.

How is Iran able to project its influence so far away from home, even though they are under US sanctions?

Answer (score 7):

First, most of the international sanctions, not just US, have been lifted in the wake of the [JCPOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action), usually called the Iran Nuclear Deal.

Iran is the center of Shia Islam, as opposed to Sunni Islam. Shia and Sunni correspond roughly to Persian and Arab, although the Muslims who aren't in either ethnic group tend to be Sunni, and there are a few cases of Persians who are Sunni and Arabs who are Shia. Lots of [longstanding grudges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia%E2%80%93Sunni_relations) between those two groups, dating back to the basic argument over who should lead Islam after Mohammed's death. Shia believe it should be a direct descendent of Mohammed, while Sunni believe it should be an elected position. The Shia have a bit of a problem with the Sunni, as Sunnis control the holy city of Mecca in Saudi Arabia.

Before that, we have Arab vs Persian, quite possibly the most longstanding grudge in human history. They really don't like each other. Never have, and probably never will.

Iran is active in Syria, Yemen, Lebanon, and Iraq, as those countries have large Shia populations, or in the case of Yemen and Syria, Shia aligned (Houthi and Alawite).

Iran is more closely aligned with Venezuela, which has a decaying economy and few friends, despite Venezuela's huge oil reserves, while both nations have a bit of a pariah status with the economic powerhouses.

Iran is simply pursuing a course of action that it sees as in its best interests. It is not really projecting power, other than very limited military support to Syria and Yemen, and while the Sunni-Shia conflict raged in Iraq, to the Shia majority there.

One other factor to be considered, is our current 'news media' and their need to stir up panic to raise ad revenue. They tend to make a mountain of a molehill on a lot of stories... good for their business, until the general population figures that out.

Comment: not an  answer...

Comment: Okay, the simple answer is - Iran is not projecting power. It's a combination of providing military support, what they've been doing with Hezbollah for ages, and a lot of media panic hype to stir up ad revenue.

Answer (score 1):

Those operations are reasonably cheap for an economically advanced state like Iran.

Iran prioritizes its regional presence and might make budget cuts elsewhere to continue to further its international goals.

Little of its defense industry has been linked to the west in recent decades, so sanctions from the US are not as meaningful to power projection as they are to quality of life of the people (McDonald's aren't called McDonald's).

Answer (score 0):

In [this link](https://www.memri.org/reports/iranian-regime-mouthpiece-kayhan-start-war-gaza-we-said-have-no-doubt-gaza-winning-%E2%80%93-and) you can read English translations of editorials of *Kayhan* -  the newspaper that is the mouthpiece of the Iranian regime and whose editor is directly appointed by Iranian Supreme Leader Ali Khamenei. They clearly explain their goals and their strategy. Some quotes:

- Their goal is to annihilate Israel: "they [the reformists] can no longer claim that destroying Tel Aviv and Haifa is a mere slogan, because this realistic slogan of the leader [Khamenei] has become a certainty on the battlefield".
- Their strategy is to employ proxies that do the "dirty job" for them: "there is no need for Iran to directly enter the war equation... McKenzie, the former commander of the American forces in the Middle East ... said: 'I personally have great respect for the plan for the drones, cruise missiles, and ballistic missiles that were manufactured over the past decade at great sacrifice, and they are like precious jewelry of the Iranian military treasury and no less important than a nuclear bomb!'"
- Also see [this statement](https://www.memri.org/tv/iran-supreme-leader-khamenei-advisor-ali-aghamohammadi-only-way-save-humanity-annihilate-israel-hizbullah-houthi-palestine-avenge-killing-razi-mousavi-soleimani) by a senior Iranian official: "'The Only Way To Save Humanity Is To Annihilate Israel'; 'Hizbullah, Houthis, Palestinians Will Avenge The Killing Of Qods Force General Razi Mousavi'".

This explains the "why". But the OP asks "how?". As far as I see, the IRGC's strategy works as follows:

- Identifying countries with a weak central government, mainly due to a civil war, such as: Lebanon, Syria, Iraq and Yemen.
- Identifying one of the factions which is religiously closer to them (e.g. Shiite or close to that).
- Flooding that faction with money and advanced weapons.
- Once that faction becomes dependent on Iran, they no longer care about the interests of the local population in their country - they become effectively Iranian agents, serving the IRGC interests.